# MySql query to get minute winner

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with always 1000 rows and a time column in the format hh:mm:ss. I need to count and get winner from minutes.

### Something like:

|12:01:00|

|14:09:00|

|03:01:00|

|14:03:00|

|08:08:00|

So in this example minute 01 is the winner.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: *So in this example minute 01 is the winner.* Why?

Comment: These documentations might help: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @Akina because it happens twice. And the other minutes just once.

Comment: @AndyLester Just asked some insight to get the result, and not to write the code. But I appreciate the tip. I got the answer below without any code. ;-) Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get minute from the time using minute(date column) if it is MySQL or date_part(minute, date column) if it is in redshift DB or use mid() if it's a string.
Then do a group by with this extracted column and count it and find the winner.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! Do you believe I would need subquery?

Comment: I didn't know about SELECT MINUTE before. I'll try something from this. Appreciate your insight. Good job for a New Contributor.